# Adding New Paragraph with onkeypress attribute

Tags: html, onkeydown, onkeypress

I was thinking onkeypress attribute is triggered repeatedly while a key is pressed. It is usually true but when I try to add a new paragraph with this attribute it sometimes doesn't work. Could you please explain me the reason why the second code doesn't work as intended as the first one works?

This is the first code to test the keypress attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Keypress</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="keypress_example()">
<div id="message">
</div>

<script>    
    function keypress_example(){
        var newPar = document.createElement('p');
        newPar.textContent= "Key is being pressed";
        document.getElementById("message").appendChild(newPar);
    }    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works as intented. The problem begins when I add also an onkeydown attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Keypress</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="keypress_example()" onkeydown="keydown_example()">
<div id="message">
</div>

<script>    
    function keydown_example(){
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "A key was pressed";
    }

    function keypress_example(){
        var newPar = document.createElement('p');
        newPar.textContent= "A key is being pressed";
        document.getElementById("message").appendChild(newPar);
    }    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you do the same for this code firstly the keydown event is triggered once, after that the keypress event triggered once but it is not triggered again and again. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Could it be because you don't have it searching for an onkeyup event, so once the initial key is pressed, to the script, it's not searching for another one because logically it's still being pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keypress` and `keydown` both repeat while the user holds the key down. Read more at [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)

If you append the new paragraph elements to a different element you get the desired behaviour. What was happening in your code was the keydown handler was replacing all existing paragraph elements and then keypress would add one. Below code works as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Keypress</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="keypress_example()" onkeydown="keydown_example()">
<div id="message"> </div>
<div id="boxes"> </div>

<script>    
    function keydown_example(){
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "A key was pressed";
    }

    function keypress_example(){
        var newPar = document.createElement("p");
        newPar.innerHTML= "A key is being pressed";
        document.getElementById("boxes").appendChild(newPar);
    }    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware onkeydown attribute is triggered repeatedly. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to close your input tag so your HTML is valid:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="keypress_example()" onkeydown="keydown_example()" />
```

Next, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Your code works.  Both events fire - and both events update the "message" div.  However, since they both fire with each keystroke - and they both update the "message" div, it will ALWAYS contain "A key was pressed" followed by a paragraph with the text 'A key is being pressed" - as long as the key you're hitting will fire BOTH events.  Some will not - like Backspace or Spacebar.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer, but I want to add that as far as I know the input tag doesn't have to be closed in HTML5. It seems what I missed was that I wasn't aware of that both attributes are repeatedly triggered when the key is being holded pressed.

Comment: Understood regarding input tag.  However, your problem wasn't the repeated triggering of your functions, rather your problem was that you were overwriting the same div's contents.

Comment: I agree, but I was thinking that the onkeydown attribute will not be fired again and again therefore I was assuming that when I was holding the key pressed onkeydown attribute wouldn't be fired after the first time and wouldn't overwrite the same div's content. By the way your answer was helpful too but I had to choose only one answer as accepted. Therefore the only thing I could do was upvoting your answer. Thanks for your help.